# In Uldir on Zul, do the Bloodhexers have the healing ability on normal, or only heroic/mythic difficulty?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Looking at [this](https://www.mmo-champion.com/content/7951-Zul-Reborn-Guide-WoW-Uldir-Boss-Strategies-and-Loot) guide, it appears that the [healing ability](https://www.wowhead.com/spell=276093/sanguine-presence) is only on Heroic. But in the fight, I was noticing that the Bloodhexers had the buff that if they were in 20 yards it would heal all ally's, and it was in the dungeon journal under normal.

During the fight I can't remember it happening though, and our guild is discussing strats.

**Does Sanguine Presence activate on normal difficulty, or only on heroic/mythic?**

Answer (score 4):

The Sanguine Presence buff is visible on the Bloodhexers on normal mode, but it does not activate. This is a display bug. The mechanic can't be found in the normal dungeon journal, and there is video evidence on Asmongold's stream from Tuesday that Bloodhexers on normal mode can be within 20 yards of each other and Zul without Zul healing:

https://www.twitch.tv/videos/305795677?t=02h47m10s (visible around 2h47 minutes into the stream) shows the Bloodhexer adds clearly within 20 yards of each other without Zul healing.

Comment: Its a good thing we are still Beta testing this raid. Such a shame these bugs aren't caught, I could have sworn I was able to see the mechanic in the normal dungeon guide but maybe it was a 3rd party. Thank you.

Comment: This answer is correct. The raid has been out for a month or so now and it is confirmed that the healing ability is not present on normal difficulty.